# How can I manipulate (decrease) cognitive load in an online survey?

Tags: cognitive, cognitive-load

I am looking for ways to decrease cognitive load (or increase cognitive capacity) in an online survey. The subjects in the survey need to make an investment decision. They will see an innovative product and they have to decide if they would invest in this product. When they have a high cognitive load they tend to make wrong decisions and invest in products that are not profitable. I want to manipulate the cognitive load to see if the subjects stop investing in unprofitable products and only invest in the profitable ones. I found examples on how to increase the cognitive load (e.g. give them less time to decide or let them memorize a number while they make the decision) but not on how to decrease it.

I thought about forcing the subject to think about the decision they have to make by giving them a minimum time (e.g. they can't continue to the next question for 60 seconds). The problem is, that I can't find a paper where they used this in an online survey. I would like to have something that proofs that this way works.

An example is in the paper "[The effect of cognitive load on decision making with graphically displayed uncertainty information](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4063894/)" by Allen et al. The authors let the subjects memorize an 8 digit-number in the high cognitive load condition and in the low cognitive condition the subjects had no memorizing task.

In my case I want to especially decrease the cognitive load and not just give one group a task to increase their cognitive load and do nothing with the second group.

Comment: Interesting question! Here are some initial ideas, too concise as an answer for the time being: (1) The way you phrase it, it seems like the _task itself_ might be too cognitively demanding. If not, increasing the cognitive load in one condition vs. merely relying on the inherent cognitive load of the task itself in the control condition should be an option, no? Thus lowering the complexity of the _task itself_ could be one option. (2) Or possibly, you are trying to control for people making rash decisions. In case you would want to _force_ them to think longer, you could include an incentive.